# Get values of object from .map in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, mapping

I'm currently working with react to read and display the elements given in a json file.
As far as this, everything works fine. Now I want to display a text in a label of a checkbox which should also be able to contain links without turning the whole label in a link.
To do this I made this json structure:

```
       "labels": [
          "Text without a link",
          {
            "url": "google.de",
            "label": "Link text"
          }
        ]
```

And to display these side by side I'm mapping over the json Array "labels"

```
    labels: Array<Object>;

    labels.map(el => {
      if (isString(el))
        return el;
      else
        return <Link href={el['url']} color="inherit">{el['label']}</Link>
    })
```

But I can't access el['url'] or el['label']. 
It throws:

```
"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Object'."
```

Probably I'm just overseeing something unbelievable simple. Help would be nice!

Cheers,
m3_

Comment: `labels: Array<Object>;` -> `labels: Array<string | {url: string; label: string}>;`?

Comment: It should be `el[1].url` and `el[1].label`

Comment: @TomFinney Thanks! That solved it. I forgot to specify the object inside labels.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return <Link href={el.url} color="inherit">{el.label}</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = {
    "labels": [
        "Text without a link", {
            "url": "google.de",
            "label": "Link text"
        }
    ]
}

const links = data.labels.map(item => {
    if(isString(item)) {
        return item
    }

    const { url, label } = item
    return <Link href={ url } color="inherit">{ label }</Link>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`"labels": [
          "Text without a link",
          {
            "url": "google.de",
            "label": "Link text"
          }
        ]`
here, labels is an array which has values of type string and object. For strings it wont have url and label properties. So while parsing every value using map function, you have to check the type of value is object or not. If it is an object then only check url and label for it.